# Laptop Fan not turning on at all

Tags: 12.04, hp, fan

I installed 12.04 64-bit onto my HP DV7 3063cl and completely removed Windows 7.

When I had Windows 7 the fan worked, but once the Ubuntu installation was complete it doesn’t even turn on during the boot process.

In the BIOS the fan is set to always on and that is the only setting regarding the fan. I currently have a sensor installed on the machine to watch the temperature as I work on the machine with a little fan under it, but what can I do to get the fan working?

Answer (score 1):

I decieded to open up the laptop, i cleaned out the fan, and the motherboard, finally in applied new thermal paste while it was open, and it magically work

Comment: OK. Choose this is the "correct answer"